# a new object get created when the export task runs: exporting cloudwatch logs to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to move CloudWatch logs from a log groups to an s3 bucket

in the bucket I have three objects (folders) :
Test, Dev, Prod

When I create an export task specifying the dev folder for example as an S3 bucket prefix,  the logs stream are successfully exported, but the problem is another folder is created with the name of the taskID in dev folder as a subfolder !

[image]

[image]
Any way to put the logs stream directly to the dev folder or this is uncontrolled behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to send the logs as files only using `export task`, as from AWS point of view you export a collection of items. Another problem, is that `export task` cannot be done automatically, it's just a manual step (Not suitable if you want to do this operation multiple times for the whole cloud watch logs, or whenever there is a new logs generated.)

> Another Solution:

You could implement your own `AWS lambda` to be triggered based on `scheduled time` to import only the files from every `AWS cloudWtach` log Group you want.

Also, storing logs can get bigger and bigger in the future and you don't always need to retrieve them in a short period, so it's not a great solution for storing logs on the long run from a `Cost` perspective, you could use `Glacier` for this purpose after you transfer your logs to `AWS S3` using `storage class transition`

Corner Case: AWS only allows one Export Task running per account. This means that if the lambda function try to export multiple log groups at once, you will get a `LimitExceededException` error.

[Please refer to this tutorial of how to implement such a solution.](https://dnx.solutions/exporting-cloudwatch-logs-automatically-to-s3-with-a-lambda-function/)

> Based on your comment on the answer:

No there is no way around for you to directly copy the logs from the `logGroup` as files, as by default `AWS` put the `task_id` of the exported logs as the name of the collection of the logs and `this cannot be changed` as it's `uncontrolled behavior`.

Also, There will be always a sub-directory that will be generated due to you need to set the `destinationPrefix` and if you didn't specify it in the request, then the default will be `exportedlogs`, as follow using [Boto3 CloudWatchLogs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.create_export_task):

```
response = logs.create_export_task(
            logGroupName=log_group_name,
            fromTime=from_to_time,
            to=export_to_time,
            destination=S3_BUCKET,
            destinationPrefix=custom_task_id.strip("/")
        )
        print("Task created: %s" % response['taskId'])
```

But you can Copy the log files after the `CreateExportTask API` finishes from the created sub-directory and then delete every file you copy, but before that you need to list all the items before every deletation to know when to stop and when to delete the sub-directory.

To summerize:

1- List items inside the bucket sub-directory.

2- copy a file to a new one (removing the taskId from the file name and leave the `destinationPerfix`).

3- delete the original.

4- iterate until you copy and delete all the logs inside the `taskId directory` on a single run of your lambda `OR` you can invoke your lambda multiple times based on the number of the logs inside your `taskId sub-directory`.

4- Delete the whole sub-directory (`taskId` directory)

This is a sample code, using boto3:

```
import sys, traceback, json
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
BUCKET_NAME = '<Bucket Name>'
LOG_GROUP_NAME = 'export-task-test'


def copy_object(src_key, dst_key):
   try:
     result = s3.copy_object(
        Bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
        CopySource='%s/%s' % (BUCKET_NAME, src_key),
        Key=dst_key
    )
     result = True
   except:
     traceback.print_exc()
     result = False
return result


def delete_object(src_key):
  try:
    s3.delete_object(
        Bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
        Key=src_key
    )
    result = True
  except:
    traceback.print_exc()
    result = False
return result


def cleanup_objects(src_key):
   # Delete Old Object & aws-logs-write-test Object
   return delete_object(src_key) and delete_object('exportedlogs/aws-logs-write-test')


def move_log(src_key):
  result = False
  group_stream_log_list = [LOG_GROUP_NAME] + src_key.split('/')[-2:]
  # <LogGrpupName>/<LogStreamName>/<LogName>
  dst_key = '/'.join(group_stream_log_list)
  return copy_object(src_key, dst_key)


def move_log_and_cleanup_objects(record):
  src_key = record['s3']['object']['key']
  event_name_category = record['eventName'].split(':')[0]
  if event_name_category != 'ObjectCreated':
    return 'Skipped: %s %s' % (event_name_category, src_key)
  if not move_log(src_key):
    return 'Failed to move %s' % src_key
  if not cleanup_objects(src_key):
    return 'Failed to cleanup %s' % src_key
  return 'Successfully moved %s' % src_key


def lambda_handler(event, context):
  record = event['Records'][0]
  result = move_log_and_cleanup_objects(record)
  print(result)
  return result
```

[Please, refer to this detailed solution of how to implement the above using lambda if your logs is not that intensive](https://medium.com/@shunku/how-to-remove-export-task-id-from-the-key-name-of-the-log-exported-with-createexporttask-api-in-a086a3df48ea)

This may be an intensive task based on the number of logs you have and also if you need to change the name of the `TaskId` for the  whole logs you imported to your `S3 bucket` at once to cut-off the time needed to interrupt every log to change it's name, if you have thousands of logs, as this will add an overhead time, so you may need to go to another serverless architecture as using `AWS ECS` and `AWS Fargate` by putting all your code in a container and trigger based on a [ECS Scheduled Task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduled_tasks.html), which will start the Fargate container at certain times of day, the container will stop once the process exits, but you will achieve un-limited timeout this solution gives you and the best Cost you can get for this task.

Comment: Yes this what we are doing: using lambda function to be triggered on a specific time, just for simplicity purposes i'm asking directly why this Task id is generated as well as a subdirectory , so there is no other solution to put the logs directly to the folder prod /dev...?

Comment: Thank you for the response, I checked the link you provided https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ko_kr/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_CreateExportTask.html , but i didn't find anything that said that a subdirectory is generated with the task id as a name

Comment: @HamzaAZIZ, please see my updated answer.

Comment: @HamzaAZIZ If my answer, answers your question. Please accept it as the right answer.

Comment: i appreciate your effort and time, but sorry it didn't answer my question yet, you said that the documentation said that's not possible, and you mentioned the link, but I checked the link and found nothing related to what you've said

Comment: @HamzaAZIZ i updated my answer with a boto3 example, i mentioned `AWS DOCS` to be a general reference as i don't know which language you use for writing your lambda, but if you saw my new example related to boto3, it demonstrate that it's not possible to not having a prefix at all and put your logs directly in your `S3 Bucket`, as even if you didn't add the `prefix` in the request, it will be added as a default value for you, so refer back to the answer starting from `There will be always a sub-directory that will be generated due to you need to set the destinationPrefix`.

Comment: yes, we're using boto3 , and we are already using a prefix in the request (dev / prod/...), but a new subdirectory with the taskID as a name is created under the prefix each time the export happen, which we don't like to have

Comment: @HamzaAZIZ maybe i didn't read the question carefully, `this behavior is uncontrolled` as this is done from `AWS` side automatically, without any option to change this in the `API`. As a result, i included a sample code to demonstrate how to get around this behavior and also a link to full article that talks in-depth about how to setup the whole solution. I searched a lot to find something in the Docs that state that we can't change this behavior but i didn't found and also didn't found anything that stated that we can change the behavior, so there isn't anything for now except a workaround.